# Named pipe connection from c++ to Java Line with space between each char

Tags: java, c++, string, pipe, named-pipes

**Hello,**

I'm transferring data from a c++ program to java using **named pipes**.

my issue is that each line i read is received with **one space (" ") between each char**, example :

```
Sent : 25343,398843292,55871844,492974923,-0.042,-0.022,2.474
Receive : 2 5 3 4 3 , 3 9 8 8 4 3 2 9 2 , 5 5 8 7 1 8 4 4 , 4 9 2 9 7 4 9 2 3 , - 0 . 0 4 2 , - 0 . 0 2 2 , 2 . 4 7 4
```

my Q is why is that happening and how can i avoid this .

code for the C++ pipe :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
///// SERVER PROGRAM /////

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    wcout << "Creating an instance of a named pipe..." << endl;

    // Create a pipe to send data
    HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        L"\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe", // name of the pipe
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, // 1-way pipe -- send only
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, // send data as a byte stream
        1, // only allow 1 instance of this pipe
        100, // no outbound buffer
        100, // no inbound buffer
        0, // use default wait time
        PIPE_ACCEPT_REMOTE_CLIENTS // use default security attributes
    );

    if (pipe == NULL || pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        wcout << "Failed to create outbound pipe instance.";
        // look up error code here using GetLastError()
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Waiting for a client to connect to the pipe..." << endl;

    // This call blocks until a client process connects to the pipe
    BOOL result = ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL);
    if (!result) {
        wcout << "Failed to make connection on named pipe." << endl;
        // look up error code here using GetLastError()
        CloseHandle(pipe); // close the pipe
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Sending data to pipe..." << endl;
    int i = 0 ;
    for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
    Sleep(25);

    // This call blocks until a client process reads all the data
    const wchar_t *data = L"25343,398843292,55871844,492974923,-0.042,-0.022,2.474\n";
    //const wchar_t *data = L"1,1,1,1,1,1,1\r\n";
    DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
    result = WriteFile(
        pipe, // handle to our outbound pipe
        data, // data to send
        wcslen(data) * sizeof(wchar_t), // length of data to send (bytes)
        &numBytesWritten, // will store actual amount of data sent
        NULL // not using overlapped IO
    );


    if (result) {
        wcout << "Number of bytes sent: " << numBytesWritten << endl;
    } else {
        wcout << "Failed to send data." << endl;
        // look up error code here using GetLastError()
    }

    }
    // Close the pipe (automatically disconnects client too)
    CloseHandle(pipe);

    wcout << "Done." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Code from java that reads the pipe :

```
public void run() {
        mIsOn = true;
        RandomAccessFile pipe = null;
        try {
            pipe = new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe", "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Main loop
        while (mIsOn) {
            String inData="";
            try {
                // Read from the pipe one line at a time
                inData = pipe.readLine();
                if (inData != null) {
                    System.out.println("Read from pipe :" + inData);//**Here it prints with spaces**
                    parseData(inData);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // Close the pipe at the end
        try {
            pipe.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

** if you wonder what happnes in parseData() then dont , cause the spaces are before that in the System.out(Read from pipe :" +data)

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29 It looks like readLine doesn't handle Unicode string correctly. You need to do something else in Java program, or send ANSI string from C++.

Comment: Yes i saw that , but if the chars seems to pass then i assume it does support the chars im sending which  are ( 0..9 - , . ) . still dont know where the spaces are from ..

Comment: Spaces are coming from 0 bytes in Unicode string. Fix the Java part of this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wide characters when sending and regular java strings when receiving.
wchar_t is usually 2 bytes, so the c++ app sends 2 bytes for every character in your strings. The java app then reads that and creates a string based on 1-byte characters.

You need to either use normal characters when sending, or receive them as bytes and convert them before creating a string.

Comment: Thank you this looks like the problem , but i'm a total noob at c++ , can you give me a code example that Will make it one byte ?

Comment: Replace all instances of wchar_t with char and all instances of wcout with cout. That should fix it.

Do note, however, that you won't be able to send wide characters over the pipe anymore. If you're just sending numbers, letters, common symbols then it's fine.